Call to a member function parameters() on null
Trying to serve laravel application using nginx and was getting a 504 error. Tried running the application through Herd and was shown the error in the title 'Call to a member function parameters() on null'.
The error occurs when I do $response = $kernel->handle($request); on line 35.
This is my public/index.php:
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

echo "Attempting to load bootstrap/app.php...\n";
try {
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    echo "bootstrap/app.php loaded successfully.\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error loading bootstrap/app.php: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

try {
    $kernel = $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
    if (!$kernel) {
        dd('Null kernel');
    }

    $request = Request::capture();
    if (!$request) {
        dd('Request capture failed');
    };

    // dd("Request captured success \n");

    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    if ($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Response) {
        echo "Response Status: " . $response->getStatusCode();
        echo "\nResponse Content: " . $response->getContent();
        echo "\nResponse Headers: " . print_r($response->headers->all(), true);

        // Clear any existing output buffers
        if (ob_get_length()) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        // Send the response
        $response->send();
    } else {
        echo "Invalid response object.";
    }
    // dd($response);
    if (!$response) {
        dd('Null response');
    };
    // dd("Response success \n");
    
    dd($response, $request);
    $response->send();
    dd("Response sent successfully.\n");
   

    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // dd(__LINE__,$e);
    echo "Error handling request: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

Went through each line and added dds after different lines to see where the error would have been.
Attempting to load bootstrap/app.php... bootstrap/app.php loaded successfully. Response Status: 500 Response Content: blah...blah...blah
Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:
foreach ($route->parameters() as $key => $value) {


The code you have shown doesn't contain a call of a method named parameters anywhere. The error message should have included file name and line number, no?

@CBroe I edited the question. The location of the error that I said was wrong earlier. Its on line 35 when doing $response = $kernel->handle($request)

replace the catch Exception at the end with catch \Throwable and log the track trace

likely you have something wrong in some middleware

@CBroe Illuminate\Routing\Router.php: foreach ($route->parameters() as $key => $value) {

@krisgjika Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:             foreach ($route->parameters() as $key => $value) {

post the full stack trace

@krisgjika array:1 [▼ // public\index.php:62
0 => array:3 [▼
"file" => "C:\Program Files\Herd\resources\app.asar.unpacked\resources\valet\server.php"
"line" => 139
"function" => "require"
]
]
is this what you mean?
